# dygraph: how to have string values in x-axis

Tags: dygraphs

I have requirements like plotting a graph for 'salesman wise sales', 'department-wise income ' etc... When I try giving string values in x-axis i am getting errors like below.

**Couldn't parse Ahmed as a date**

please help.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values other than `date` or `float` are prohibited for `x-values`. See [Data Format](http://dygraphs.com/data.html). However you may put your `string` values in an `array` and use indexes instead of actual `string` values.

See [`xValueParser`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#xValueParser), [`valueFormatter`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#valueFormatter) and [`axisLabelFormatter`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#axisLabelFormatter) as well.